# Python- Calling Functions

Tags: python, function

I apologise in advance that this is a really nooby question. Just out of curiosity, what is the difference between (for example) function(a) and a.function()? Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `function(a)` and `a.function()` is the difference between a function and a method. A function is called `function(a)` and is not called on a variable. `a.function()` is actually a method and is called on an instance variable. When `a.function()` is called, whatever class `a` is, has a method `function()` that can be called on that variable. Whereas, when `function(a)` is called, a function is called with `a` as the parameter. An example of this is

```
' '.join(['a','b','c'])
```

The method `join` is called on the string `' '` (as `join` is a method that belongs to the `str` class) and takes the parameter `['a', 'b', 'c']`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Example():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1

    def change_x(self):
        self.x = 5
        print(self.x)

def example_function(x):
    print(x)

a= Example()
a.change_x()  #calling the object function of 

example_function("hello")  #calling the function in scope

#prints >> 5
#       >> hello
```

When you `something.function()` you are calling the function of that object.

When you are `function()` you are calling the function within scope that is defined in your namespace.